# Sporadic java.security.AccessControlException when accessing NFS share

Tags: java, websphere, aix, nfs

I have a Web Application running in WebSphere that uses Java 2 Security and has the permission to access a directory which is a mounted NFS share. Normally everthing works fine. But sometimes starting the application fails with:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/mounted/nfs_share" "read")
```

Currently all I can do in this case is to restart the server.

Some details to my environment:

- OS: AIX 6.1
- NFS 3
- WebSphere 8.5
- Java 7

What is causing this effect? If the NFS share temporarily wasn't available (e.g. network problems) I would expect IOExceptions when actually accessing it, but no SecurityExceptions in advance.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
[4/15/16 13:49:45:565 CEST] 00000078 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                             org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.tsystems.cc4.service.invocation.spring.InvocationWrapperBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [component-service-zip.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/mounted/nfs_share" "read")
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:682)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1707)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:411)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1382)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:971)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5477)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/mounted/nfs_share" "read")
    at java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:121)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:194)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:563)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:208)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:902)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:820)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:2367)
    at com.tsystems.cc4.common.attachment.LocalFileAccessor.getCanonicalBaseDirectory(LocalFileAccessor.java:197)
    at com.tsystems.cc4.common.attachment.LocalFileAccessor.<init>(LocalFileAccessor.java:92)
    at com.tsystems.cc4.common.attachment.LocalFileAccessor.<init>(LocalFileAccessor.java:112)
    at com.tsystems.cc4.common.attachment.AttachmentManagerFactory.createAttachmentManager(AttachmentManagerFactory.java:40)
    at com.tsystems.cc4.service.invocation.spring.AbstractInvocationWrapperBeanPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractInvocationWrapperBeanPostProcessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Stacktrace:  
    `Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/mounted/nfs" "read")
        at java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:121)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:194)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:563)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:208)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:902)
        at java.io.File.exists(File.java:820)`

Comment: Without more stack trace (what is calling File.exists? what is calling that code?) it's hard to give specific advice.  Typically, there is a CWSCJ0314E message in SystemOut.log that will give the specific class and codebase that are at fault.

Comment: I added the stack trace to my description. My application is a Spring-based Web Module. The exception occurs when WebSphere starts the Web Module and Spring creates all beans from the Spring context. However, the exception occurs sporadically and not always in the same Web Module (the application actuallly consists of many Web Modules, all built on Spring).